# Google TaskQueue (pull) insert task by API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, task-queue, pull-queue

I'm using the apiclient.discovery.build to lease tasks from a Google Pull Queue.. It's working fine.. But when I try to insert tasks in this Queue, I always get the same error:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
build = build('taskqueue', 'v1beta2', credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

# Works
resp = build.tasks().lease(project=project,taskqueue=name,leaseSecs=lease_time,numTasks=num_tasks).execute()

# Error
payload = {'payloadBase64': 'c29tZSB0ZXN0'}
result = build.tasks().insert(project=project,taskqueue=name,body=payload)
```

> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>   googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta2/projects/project_test/taskqueues/pullqq/tasks?alt=json
>   returned "Backend Error">

The authentication is correct because I can lease/delete tasks.. It might be some missing field in the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I changed the payload with the exactly payload from the leased tasks.. except for some fields (e.g., ID or leasing time) and added the '~s' to the project name in 'queueName'.

```
resp = {u'kind': u'taskqueues#task', u'queueName': u'projects/s~project_name/taskqueues/pullqq', u'payloadBase64': u'c29tZSB0ZXN0'}
```

Now it worked.